# closure of a set of smooth functions with imposed conditions on a part of a boundary

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a smooth $C^1$ bounded domain, set $U := \{ u \in C^\infty(\Omega\times[0,T]) \text{ s.t. } u=0 \text{ on }\partial \Omega\times [0,T]\}$ and take V to be the closure of U with respect to the $H^1(\Omega\times[0,T])$ norm.

Is it possible to prove that $V \equiv \{ u \in H^1(\Omega\times[0,T]) \text{ s.t. } u =0 \text{ on }\partial \Omega\times [0,T]\}$ ?

Any hint or reference(s) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a way, but for the time being it seems tedious and I hope to find a more straitforward answer.

According to Ladyzenskaja p. 89 lemma 4.12 (Equations of parabolic type...)
, the set of functions of the form $\sum_{k=1}^N d_k(t)\psi_k(x)$ are dense in V (I think this is reasonable and not difficult to show), where $d_k(t) \in C^\infty([0,T])$ whereas $(\psi_k)_{k\in{\mathbb N}}$ is a fundamental system of functions in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Then approximating each of the vectors of the $H^1_0(\Omega)$ basis by density of ${\mathcal D}(\Omega)$ functions since the number $N$ is finite, does the job.

The funny thing seems to be that this works even for Lipschitz domains $\Omega$ since the density holds